# Delete same rows from list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of lists in python. 
I would like to remove the rows what first element is already in the block.

```
block = [
    ['alfa', 'T31360N', '2013-12-19 12:07:2'],
    ['beta', 'D41535N', '2013-12-19 12:20:1'],
    ['gamma', 'E61460N', '2013-12-19 13:58:2'],
    ['delta', 'D133PR01', '2013-12-19 14:19:4'],
    ['beta', 'Q3332N', '2013-12-19 14:19:5']
]
```

How can I delete the 'beta' started rows from the list?

Comment: Do you mean a list of lists? There is no such thing as a *block* in Python.

Comment: Yes. I mean list of lists. sorry

Comment: Did you want to remove *both* the lists that start with `'beta'`? Or just the second one?

Comment: If it is not a problem I would like to see both solutions :-).
Mainly I would like to delete only the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order) to your list:

```
seen = set()
block = [row for row in block if row[0] not in seen and not seen.add(row[0])]
```

This *rebuilds* `block` to only contain rows that have a unique first element; so only the first row with a given first value is kept.

To keep just the unique rows and remove all rows that have *more than one* entry, you need to use a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to track how many times each first element is present, *then* trim `block`:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(row[0] for row in block)
block = [row for row in block if counts[row[0]] == 1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> block = [
...     ['alfa', 'T31360N', '2013-12-19 12:07:2'],
...     ['beta', 'D41535N', '2013-12-19 12:20:1'],
...     ['gamma', 'E61460N', '2013-12-19 13:58:2'],
...     ['delta', 'D133PR01', '2013-12-19 14:19:4'],
...     ['beta', 'Q3332N', '2013-12-19 14:19:5']
... ]
>>> seen = set()
>>> pprint([row for row in block if row[0] not in seen and not seen.add(row[0])])
[['alfa', 'T31360N', '2013-12-19 12:07:2'],
 ['beta', 'D41535N', '2013-12-19 12:20:1'],
 ['gamma', 'E61460N', '2013-12-19 13:58:2'],
 ['delta', 'D133PR01', '2013-12-19 14:19:4']]
>>> counts = Counter(row[0] for row in block)
>>> pprint([row for row in block if counts[row[0]] == 1])
[['alfa', 'T31360N', '2013-12-19 12:07:2'],
 ['gamma', 'E61460N', '2013-12-19 13:58:2'],
 ['delta', 'D133PR01', '2013-12-19 14:19:4']]
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing `seen = set()` rather than `seen = []` and changing `seen.add()` to `seen.append()`?

Comment: @TomFenech: No, because `set` membership testing is much faster.

Comment: Thanks. That should have been phrased better. I was assuming that you'd picked the better way, I was just wondering why!